# My machine has a global IPv6 address but can't access the internet via IPv6

Tags: networking, ipv6

I installed two Operating Systems in my machine, One is Ubuntu 16.04 and another is Windows7. In Windows7, it can access to IPv6 network, but in Ubuntu 16.04, it fails. My computer, worked well with IPv6 in the past, has a global IPv6 address, and my router support IPv6 network.

The follows are some configuration of my OS.  Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

- The output of `ifconfig` (there is a global IPv6 address):

  ```
  eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:b1:1c:a5:38:58  
        inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: 2403:ac00:0:4001::1:e0e1/128 Scope:Global
        inet6 addr: fe80::92b1:1cff:fea5:3858/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:116994 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:102110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:85012005 (85.0 MB)  TX bytes:14755369 (14.7 MB)
        Interrupt:20 Memory:f7100000-f7120000 

  lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:115589 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:115589 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
        RX bytes:19332159 (19.3 MB)  TX bytes:19332159 (19.3 MB)
  ```
- The output of `sudo route -nv -A inet6`:

  ```
  Kernel IPv6 routing table
  Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
  2403:ac00:0:4001::1:e0e1/128   ::                         Ue   256 0     0 eth0
  fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
  ::/0                           fe80::7ea2:3eff:fe8b:87e   UG   100 1     0 eth0
  ::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1  2785 lo
  ::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   1    11 lo
  2403:ac00:0:4001::1:e0e1/128   ::                         Un   0   1  1692 lo
  fe80::92b1:1cff:fea5:3858/128  ::                         Un   0   1     6 lo
  ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
  ::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1  2785 lo
  ```
- The output of `tracepath6 sv`:

  ```
  traceroute to SV (2607:8700:109:1d2a::) from 2403:ac00:0:4001::1:e0e1, 30 hops max, 24 byte packets
   1  2403:ac00:0:4001::1:e0e1 (2403:ac00:0:4001::1:e0e1)  2997.43 ms !H  2999.29 ms !H  3000.08 ms !H
  ```
- The output of `traceroute6 sv`:

  ```
   1?: [LOCALHOST]                        0.223ms pmtu 1500
   1:  2403:ac00:0:4001::1:e0e1                            2999.781ms !H
       Resume: pmtu 1500
  ```
- The output of `ping6 www.google.com`:

  ```
  PING www.google.com(www.google.com) 56 data bytes
  From www.google.com icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
  From www.google.com icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
  From www.google.com icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
  ```
- The output of `ssh sv`:

  ```
  ssh: connect to host 2403:ac00:0:4001::2:df7c port 22: No route to host
  ```

Comment: Can you ping fe80::7ea2:3eff:fe8b:87e

Comment: @meccooll The output of `ping fe80::7ea2:3eff:fe8b:87e` is `ping unknown host fe80::7ea2:3eff:fe8b:87e`, it seems that the command is only used for IPv6. The output of `ping6 fe80::7ea2:3eff:fe8b:87e` is `connect: Invalid argument`.

Comment: Sorry need to specify interface when using a linklocal (fe80::) addresses so try `ping -I eth0 fe80::7ea2:3eff:fe8b:87e`

Comment: @meccooll The output is :
`PING fe80::92b1:1cff:fea5:3858(fe80::92b1:1cff:fea5:3858) from fe80::92b1:1cff:fea5:3858 eth0: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::92b1:1cff:fea5:3858: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms`
It seems ok.

Comment: Wait why is you subnet /128 in `inet6 addr: 2403:ac00:0:4001::1:e0e1/128 Scope:Global` ? That's probably your issues.

Comment: @meccooll My router is "Netgear genie WNR2000v4", which supports IPv6 networking, and the IPv6 mode of my router is "Pass Through". The `/128` address is automatically configured. In the past, `/128` address was OK.

Comment: You should include the output of `ip -6 neigh` in the question.